# Can't connect to Bluetooth speaker

Tags: 16.04, sound, bluetooth

My web server, mail server, VOIP server is running Lubuntu 16.04.1, Kernel 4.4.0-64-generic, blueman-manager 2.0.4 .

I've got a new cheap Bluetooth speaker SP-A132, which is just for a VoIP phone ringer.

It says it uses protocols A2DP v1.2 and AVRCP.

blueman-manager won't recognise it, let alone pair with  it, let alone play sound.  It can see bluetooth keyboard OK.

I can see there have been many problems discussed once we are passed the pairing phase, but I think this is different, and nearly a year on from 16.04 release.

My Android smartphone can pair with and it plays OK.

I don't want to be doing complex stuff on this server box.

Should I just take the new gadget back?

EDIT

$ lsusb | grep bluetooth

Bus 001 Device 019: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)